# Problems of small training dataset vs. large test dataset

Tags: random-forest, small-sample, large-data

I am currently working on a problem where my training dataset is very limited in size (few thousands of rows). Any model I develop on this needs to predict the outcome on a dataset millions of rows in size. I wanted to know what might be the possible problems that one might face when the training dataset is a few thousands of rows and test dataset is millions of rows?

> 1. Because of the size disparity, more often than not, the output (classification/regression) will have a different distribution than in
>      the original dataset. Is this a problem?
> 2. What are the common pitfalls I need to keep in mind while in this scenario?
> 3. If you want to answer specific to an algorithm - go at it with 'Random Forests'

Comment: By test set do you mean the predictions you'll have to make when your model gets deployed into production and has to make live predictions? Or are you referring to a partition of data that you already have?

Comment: The former. The dataset on which my model will have to make predictions once it goes into production

Answer (score 4):

The number of predictions you'll have to make once your model goes into production doesn't matter. The real problem is overfitting on a small training dataset. Regarding your specific questions:

1. If the distributions differ, then you should re-sample the training dataset so that it more closely resembles what you expect to see in production. This won't work if the two sets are extremely different. The degree of difference is a rule of thumb that you'll have to decide based on your domain expertise.
2. Use simpler and smaller models for smaller datasets. An obvious example would be: don't assign more trees to your random forest than there are data points in your training data set. If your dataset is very small (several hundred records) then you should probably use a linear model. If you have an imbalanced data set (e.g., predicting fraud, which doesn't happen often) and the class of interest occurs only 1% of the time, then several thousand rows is *very* small, and you'll probably only want to use a linear model.

Comment: Interesting. Several thousand rows is less for class imbalanced data because there is not enough information for the model to learn from?

Comment: @Bach Yes, especially if the class you care most about is the minority class.

Comment: What if there was no preference to the majority or minority class? If you can point me to any reading material on this, would be really helpful!

Comment: If there is no preference for the minority class than several thousand records is probably ok for a random forest. Unfortunately I don't have any references. It's something I've experienced over the years. It was also institutional knowledge in the data science department at the very large financial services company that I used to work for. A common observation was that records in a majority class are often fairly similar such that adding a new majority class record usually won't tell you more about what *not* to expect in the minority class